# onKeyDown Only Firing with Backspace

Tags: java, android, events

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

}
```

The code within this method only fires when the selected `EditText` has a key entry of the backspace. I need it to be triggered for all key presses of any kind. This method is not within a `KeyEvent` object, rather it floats in the body of my main activity and thus should respond to *any* key press right? Why only backspace and the "Done" key? By the way I am only accepting number input.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post more of the code, it will be very helpful to debug. Especially where you configure and attach the listener.

Comment: I shall but am a little unsure what is needed of me. Right now the onKeyDown contains only some Log calls, and there are no other references to that method but for the imports. The code is meant to be anchored to the whole activity, I do not call setKeyListener or equivalent

Comment: Just to clarify the EditText isnt specifically tied to this method, which just sits within my class but isnt nested further

Comment: Is this for a stock soft keyboard?

Comment: Its the android virtual keyboard (the one for numbers only) does that answer your question? Sorry I am new at all this keyboard lingo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using a soft keyboard on a newer Android version, then the following blurb from [the KeyEvent reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) likely explains the reason you're not getting your expected key events.

"As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting text, **there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will generate a key event**: this is left to the IME's discretion, and in fact sending such events is discouraged. You should never rely on receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft input method. In particular, **the default software keyboard will never send any key event to any application targetting Jelly Bean or later**, and will only send events for some presses of the delete and return keys to applications targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier. Be aware that other software input methods may never send key events regardless of the version. Consider using editor actions like IME_ACTION_DONE if you need specific interaction with the software keyboard, as it gives more visibility to the user as to how your application will react to key presses."

Comment: Can you recommend an alternative to key events for getting the text of an EditText only when it has been changed (when the user types)?

Comment: Implement the TextWatcher interface as described by http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html . It'll let you get notified when the text changed.